# Jar execution error: could not find or load main class xxx

Tags: java, jar, apache-poi

I have already compiled and executed the java code that uses external library files from apache-poi, the code reads string from excel spreadsheet and displays it but when I tried making a executable jar file and opening it, the command prompt gives the message- `Could not find or load main class`.(Double clicking the jar file doesn't open the jar file)

I have took care in writing the `MANIFEST.MF` file by placing the newline at end and adding headers in proper order(Oracle docs), its content is-

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Class-Path: . C:\poi-3.12\poi-3.12-20150511.jar C:\poi-3.12\poi-ooxml-
 3.12-20150511.jar C:\poi-3.12\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar C:\
 poi-3.12\ooxml-lib\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar 

Created-By: 1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)

Main-Class: testfrpn
```

where `testfrpn` is the class containing `main()`(*the entrypoint*). Though there are solutions to the problem on stackoverflow(and elsewhere too) but none of it worked for me, the most common solution being *executing `jar -cvfm xxx.jar xxx.txt` in proper order*.

It should be noted that the code executes just fine(*java xxx*), the problem arises when I execute the .jar file(created through command prompt).

Quite honestly I have already spent too much of a time and too many of things to overcome the problem but have failed, so it would be really great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Is testfrpn belongs to default package or some other package?

Comment: testfrpn does belong to default package

Answer (score 1):

if it's a executable jar, the `MANIFEST.MF` file should like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: JerryZhang
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_25
Main-Class: com.company.department.SampleClassName
Class-Path: lib/poi-3.10-FINAL.jar lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar lib/poi-o
 oxml-3.8-beta4.jar lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta4.jar lib/xmlbeans-2
 .3.0.jar lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar lib/xml-apis-1.0.
 b2.jar lib/sshj-0.8.1.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar lib/commons-cli-1.2
 .jar lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar lib/logback-core-1.0.13.jar
```

The important line is:

```
Main-Class: com.company.department.SampleClassName
```

The value should include package name and class name, it tells the JVM which class is the main class.

You execute the xxxx.jar with this command:

```
java -jar xxxx.jar
```

Comment: But I had already moved to the package itself(on command line), wouldn't mentioning it again in Main-Class be erroneous?

Comment: But doesn't package name need not be included when command line is already pointing to the location of class file?